# FirebaseAuthStateListener with Launcher Activity Not Working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have setup firebase email and password login. I have three activities in my app. Register, Login and Main. In main activity, I have put Firebase AuthSateListener to detect if user exists, if not send the user to login/register activities.

The problem I guess is that my MainActivity is my launcher activity and even if there's no currently logged in user, it does not redirect to the auth activities. I don't know if my assumption is right or I'm not setting it up correctly. Here's my code so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private RecyclerView playersRV;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    init();

    authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user == null){
                Log.d(TAG, "User is null");
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "User exists:\t" + user.getEmail());
                return;
            }
        }
    };

    playersRV.setHasFixedSize(true);
    playersRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mAuth.signOut();
            mAuth = null;
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
        }
    });

}

private void init() {
    playersRV = findViewById(R.id.playersRV);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (authStateListener == null){
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (authStateListener != null){
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
        authStateListener = null;
    }

    }


}
```

My BaseActivity has variable declarations for Firebase Auth and Firebase AuthStateListener.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening this way?
Thanks.

Comment: I have solved this problem. Thanks to all who viewed and didn't respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
 //Get Firebase auth instance
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        // User is logged in - send it to home screen \\
    } else {
        //User is not logged in - send it to login screen \\
    }
```

Comment: That's great... Welcome